# Coherent sheaf restriction to closed subscheme is flat

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is one more question on flat morphisms that I have been thinking about.

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow S$ is a flat projective morphism of noetherian schemes. Both $X$ and $S$ are smooth and irreducible. Let $T$ be a smooth closed subscheme of $S$.

Suppose $F$ is a coherent $O_X$ module such that $F_T$ is flat over $T$.

Is there some additional condition which will ensure that $F$ is $S$-flat?

Comment: If $T$ is a point, then $F_T$ is flat over $T$ for any $F$. So, what kind of conditions are you expecting?

Comment: @Mohan, is there some sheaf theoretic condition? I heard that there is a condition in terms of ideal of the closed subscheme. But I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

No. Flatness is local condition. We can always ensure $F$ is misbehaved at some place outside of $T$.